# Oracle apex 5 limitations

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5

can anyone please let me know that what limitations does oracle apex have,

limitations like Storage, RAM or other.

How long will i be able to use it without licensing the database?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/install.50/e39144/pre_require.htm#HTMIG376

Comment: i searched google a lot but did not find exact response, therefore i raised this question here.

Comment: you're only limited by the database. there are limitations in Oracle Database XE when it comes to Space/RAM - but that's the db limitation's, not APEX's.

Comment: Hey  thatjeffsmith can you please elaborate a bit about the space allowed without licencing

Answer (score 3):

Oracle APEX is a no-cost feature of the Oracle Database.  If you use a free Oracle database (Oracle XE) then Oracle APEX is free to use.  You can also gain free access to Oracle APEX at http://apex.oracle.com.  If wish to use Oracle APEX on the cloud you can do so with Oracle Exadata Express (http://cloud.oracle.com/database) and many other database cloud services.  Free cloud 1 month trials may also be available.

Answer (score 0):

i found this in oracle website, and i now understand that storage differ in each version.

With respect to growing needs for storage, Oracle Database 11g XE now offers a full 11GB for user data alone, which is almost threefold increase since previous 4GB limit in Oracle Database 10g XE. Other hardware restrictions remain the same with CPU usage capped at one physical core and memory at 1GB. Oracle Database 11g XE is available immediately for Windows and Linux platforms.

Source:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-xe-quicktour-498681.html